# Print xmas tree

Tags: python, tree

I want to print xmas tree with "stump" but i dont have any idea how to get that stump in there. I use Python language. My code looks like this so far:

```
def xmas(a):
    stars = 1
    for i in range(a):
        print((' ' * (a - i)) + ('*' * stars))
        stars += 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xmas(3)
```

and it print this:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
```

And i want it to print like this:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
   *
```

Do you have any tip how to get that stump over there?

Comment: A tip: after printing the last "level" of your tree, you want to put the "stomp" right in the middle of it. Checkout both the value of `a` and `stars` at the end of your for loop for multiple values.

Comment: add print outside the for loop. ```print(' '*2 + '*')```

Answer (score 1):

Print the last line:

```
def xmas(a):
    stars = 1
    for i in range(a):
        print((' ' * (a - i)) + ('*' * stars))
        stars += 2
    print(' ' * a + '*')  # HERE

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xmas(3)
```

Output

```
   *
  ***
 *****
   *
```